# unable to run gtk apps compiled with gcc 4.4 (mingw)

Tags: gtk, mingw, gcc4.4

I have downloaded the gtk all-in-one package for windows. I am compiling my file with -mms-bitfields but still i get the error,

```
Gtk-ERROR **: Incompatible build!
The code using GTK+ thinks GtkBox is of different
size than it actually is in this build of GTK+.
On Windows, this probably means that you have compiled
your code with gcc without the -mms-bitfields switch,
or that you are using an unsupported compiler.
aborting...
```

Any ideas?

Adeel.

Answer (score 1):

You should enable -mms-bitfields in your project's properties.

Depending on what IDE you use, it might be a bit different.

In NetBeans, right click on your project. Then go to
Project Properties -> C++ Compiler. Expand Compilation Line and in Additional Options enter -mms-bitfields. Make sure that Configuration is set to All Configuration. Rebuild your project.

In Code::Blocks I think you should do, as follows: 
Right click on your project -> Build Options. Go to Compiler Settings -> Other Options and write -mms-bitfields. Make sure that you apply this change to the whole project (not just the debug or release). Rebuild your project.